# What is a compact, yet flexible, way of storing multiple key-value pairs in a single string?

Tags: performance, embedded, language-agnostic

I have two systems, `System A` and `System B`. `System A` needs to send complex data (namely key-value pairs, but all data is flat) to `System B`. However, `System B` is a very rudimentary system and can only accept one string. This can be a long string (up to 32 kB) and `System B` can perform basic manipulation on this string (splitting on delimiters, splitting at character, trimming, etc.). `System B` also has the ability to store basic information that can be used for this processing.

The goal: **A flexible solution that results in the least bytes sent between systems.**

Here's what I've considered so far:

As an example, let's say I have this data (using JSON for representation, to keep things simple):

```json
{
  "run": "T1021",
  "program": "02",
  "voltage": 12,
  "customer": "Cronus"
}
```

However, this is not **always** the structure of the data. Depending on the running job, there may be additional fields included.

Here are some options I've considered:

### JSON

JSON was what first came to mind since that is what is most common. It's very flexible and can accurately represent the data, but `System B` does not have a library for parsing JSON, meaning it would have to do basic string manipulation to get the data out.

### Concatenated String

On the other end of the flexibility spectrum would be a single concatenated string and using positions to determine the values.

For example, with the data above, the final string could look like `T10210212Cronus--------------`. Then, in `System B`, we would record the data layout:

| Field No | Length | StartDigit | Field Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | run |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | program |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | voltage |
| 4 | 20 | 13 | customer |

Then, using this logic, we can extract the values. This approach is very concise, but not flexible at all.

### Basic Key/Value Pairs

As a hybrid approach, I considered doing key-value pairs, split by a delimiter. I don't need the full features of JSON since the data will always be flat (no nesting of the data).

For example, the above sample would result in `run:T1021 program:02 voltage:12 customer:Cronus`. Then, `System B` would be able to split on a space to get each key-value pair, and then split on the colon to get the key and the value separated.

This is as flexible as JSON for this use case while removing the extra characters. However, this is nowhere near as compact as the original method. It also seems redundant to send the same key over and over again.

---

Is there another method of encoding this data into a single string that maintains flexibility, but sends fewer bytes?

Comment: Have you looked into MessagePack? It's pretty similar to what you're asking https://msgpack.org/

Comment: Why did you add the embedded tag? Is this actually intended for an embedded system? If so maybe you can give more details about which target you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<field name 1>
<field name 2>
...
<field name n>

<record 1 field value 1>
<record 1 field value 2>
...
<record 1 field value n>

<record 2 field value 1>
<record 2 field value 2>
...
<record 2 field value n>

...

<record m field value 1>
<record m field value 2>
...
<record m field value n>
```

Assuming your delimiter has length 1 and that the average value length is b and the average field name length is a then the size of such a message is (m+1)n + m + an + mbn:

```
(m+1)n delimiters after values and names
m extra delimiters between records and the names header
an characters in the names header, excluding delimiters
mbn characters in the records' values, excluding delimiters
```

This is clearly a lot less space than if we sent the names over and over again. Compared to the flat file approach with fixed width fields, whether this approach is better or worse (and to what degree it is so) depends on the variance of record value lengths: if the variance is small, the flat-file fixed-width format is superior, if there is large variance in record value lengths, this layout pulls ahead (since the fixed-width columns would have wasted space).

This format assumes there is some delimiter you can use that is distinct from the name/value characters. This is a pretty reasonable assumption normally but if your names/values could contain any characters it might be necessary to escape one somehow for this scheme to be viable.